# For each dimension $k=0, 1, ..., 12$, find the number of distinct cyclic codes $C\subset \mathbb{Z}_{13}^{12}$ of dimension $k$.

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory

> For each dimension $k=0, 1, ..., 12$, find the number of distinct cyclic codes $C\subset \mathbb{Z}_{13}^{12}$ of dimension $k$.

Currently, I'm factoring $x^{12}-1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ and got $x^{12}-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x-3)(x+3)(x-4)(x+4)(x-2)(x^5+2x^4+4x^3+5x^2+3x+6)$. However, since this factorization and computation are tedious, I'm not sure if this factorization is correct.

Also, after finding all factors of this polynomial, how should I proceed? If the above factorization is correct, this means that we can create a generator polynomial of degree k for all $k=0, 1, ..., 12$. This seems weird.

Comment: Maybe you should give some thought to the fact that $\mathbb Z_{13}$ is actually the finite field $\mathbb F_{13}$ whose nonzero elements are the _field integers_ $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12$ and so $x^{12}-1$ factors into $\prod_{k=1}^{12}(x-k)$

Answer (score 1):

(Answering since I can't comment yet.) What does Fermat's little theorem tell you about the roots of $ x^{12}-1$? When you are done factoring, it should be easy to count how many generator polynomials you have of any given degree... which is what you want to do.